# Why does the string ":n" considered same as ".n" by replaceAll() method in Java?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

Why is `:0` getting replaced when the statement is for `.0` ?

I tried it with `:x` & `.x` and on my Intellij as well as on online `gdb` compiler, but this issue persists.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "Hello:0, World:0.0, het:0";    
        System.out.println(s);

        s = s.replaceAll(".0,", ",");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello:0, World:0.0, het:0
Hello, World:0, het:0
```

Comment: Is not - its just `:` means `:` and `.` means ANY CHARACTER - and `:` fits any character rule.

Answer (score 12):

`.` means "any character", because `replaceAll` uses [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Use `replace` instead, if you want to replace the literal string:

```
s = s.replace(".0,", ",");
```

Alternatively, you can escape the `.`, either by prefixing with `\`, or using the `Pattern.quote` method:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\.0,", ",");
s = s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(".0,"), ",");
```

Comment: Just want to point out explicitly for OP, but even though they are named `replace` and `replaceAll`, they _both_ replace every occurrence, just in different ways.  It is a common source of confusion.

Comment: @Nexevis indeed. There is `replaceFirst`, if only replacing one is desired. This also uses regular expressions, so escaping would be required.

Comment: @Nexevis Thanks for the add-on tip.